# AND / OR formula solver

Tags: powershell, math

I want to simplify formulas like following:

```
(A || B) && (C || D) => (A && C) || (A && D) || (B && C) || (B && D)
A => (A)
A && (B || C) => (A && B) || (A && C)
A && B => (A && B)
A || B => (A) || (B)
```

Desired result: a list of groups combined with `||` whereas each group only contains `&&`

Does a solver for such a problem exist? Can someone help with this?

Maybe someone can tell me words that are relevant for this problem? As I don't know how this is called and formula solvers are something different...

Comment: This is not a stackoverflow question. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Why _Powershell_ tag?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to intentionally make a Boolean logic statement longer than it's already simplified state?

Comment: powershell, because I'm trying to handle the data in there. And I want to convert the formula to this format because I will use all clauses to make combinations with other values (I need all permutations of all clauses with a list of other values)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form should be useful to read.

Answer (score 1):

> Maybe someone can tell me words that are relevant for this problem? As I don't know how this is called and formula solvers are something different...

I believe that what you are looking for is the [disjunctive normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form) of a formula. Apparently you don't need the full form, as in you don't require each letter (with or without negation) to occur in each parenthesis. Which means that your result is in general not uniquely defined.

As long as your original formula doesn't contain any negations, the [distributive law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Propositional_logic) is likely the most useful tool to reorder the boolean connectives. If negations play a role as well, [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) would become relevant, too.

If you search Stack Overflow for disjunctive normal form, you will find various requests to convert to this form in various languages. Many of them will probably aim for the full form, so keep that distinction in mind when you read the answers there.

Comment: Thanks. I just forgot this description and did not find it. With DNF as search term I'll find what I need to help me solve the problem.